# firebase createUserWithEmailAndPassword not setting current user live

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

When i create a user it dosn't set the auth state i need to refresh to see it why?

with `signInWithEmailAndPassword` it set the current user right but on `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` somebody can help?

Comment: its unclear what your asking. Are you signing out the user?

Comment: No I'm creating user so on SignUp

Comment: after creating is there a currentuser or is it null?

Comment: null but if i refresh the page it's ok

Comment: its because of the internet connection

Comment: i don't think so because it's always doing that and on login it's working

Answer (score 1):

When you use this method `createUserWithEmailAndPassword`, you create a new authenticated user.

When you use this method `signInWithEmailAndPassword`, you sign in the authenticated account.

Now when using the first method, it is better to add a loading screen as it takes some time to be able to get the new authenticated user. That is why many websites/app, first you create an account then you sign in.

You can do this:

1. create account
2. sign in with new account

or

1. create account
2. add a loading dialog
3. go to home screen

Comment: so is it normal?

Comment: yes it does take time that is why it gives you null user